# Create PowerPoint Presentations based on csv/xml file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a large set of images that I'd like to create a presentation from. All the slides look the same: Centered Image, text caption, audio file. The image and Audio file have the same name, different extension. So I have a database relating

- Text
- Image
- Audio

Any idea how to create such a Powerpoint file?

**Edit**
Right now looking into creating xslt transforms and to produce a file in OpenXML format or python scripting as per http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/PowerPointCreator.aspx?fid=1525862

Looks very promising, but still can't get it to work on yet.

Comment: Documentation on PowerPoint is in MSDN is zero. Maybe dropping powerpoint for this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices for automating the creation of powerpoint presentations.

- In older versions of powerpoint there's a built in macro recording tool to create visual basic scripts. You can still manually create these scripts to automate viewgraph generation
- In more recent version of MS Office there are much better plugins for c# to create presentations (and other office files) directly from data. Here's [an older link to microsoft documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303718) (2002) but it should give you a good idea of how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think of MS automation. Our presentations each have ~1000 slides, and we will try many formats to find something that works for us. I haven't tried it yes, but I'm scared it will crash on me midway. I'll lookup documentation for ppt 2007 and try it.

Comment: another alternative is an html5 friendly app. you can checkout a few variations floating about http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-HTML5-alternative-to-Slideshare/answer/Mark-Essel